# Scraping Vine data by python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, vine

I want to get post data(such as title,like,share,content) of different brand (public account) on Vine by python.
Now I have some thoughts:

1. There is a Vine api called Vinepy from github(https://github.com/davoclavo/vinepy), however it requires you create account and use your own login info, and it seems like you could only crawling data from your own account, so can I use Vinepy to crawling data from other accounts as well? cause there are less examples about Vinepy, and I did not figure out how to do it.
2. Another alternative that I came up with is to use beautifulsoup + selenium to do this.because there is "Load More" button in vine page and you need use selenium to interact with it. But my question is can beautifulsoup + selenium handle Javascript? Cause all the posts are written by javascript frame called ember.js

Or anybody have a better ideas about how to doing it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Vine API that doesn't require login for public data:

https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference

It's not specifically Python-centric, but it's just an HTTP GET to retrieve some JSON.